# what is the use of json.simple? Can it maintain order of json inserted?

Tags: json

Can we use json.simple to maintain the order of data inserted? OR which other way is the best to have ordered JSON

```
{
 "1":"a",
 "2":"b",
 "3":"c"
}
```

It should always retain the order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/simple/JSONObject.java), it uses the `Map` iterator to output the properties in the `Map`'s order, and it's based on `HashMap`, which doesn't order its entries the way you want.

But, again looking at the source code, you could copy the `JSONObject` into a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html), which maintains its entries according to the natural ordering of its keys (or according to a `Comparator` you provide), and then use `JSONObject.writeJSONString(Map,Writer)` to output that map. Since it uses the map's iterator, that would be in key order.

---

Side note: JSON notation **has no order** to object properties. But if you're outputting them in a specific order to, for instance, allow meaningful comparison of two JSON texts, that's one reason to ensure the JSON text is output in a specific order.